# Quick links WebPart with Target Audience option

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, audience-targeting, quick-links

Does any one know how to create Quick Links Web Part with Target Audience option in SharePoint online modern pages?

I need to enable the links specific users only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft is working on this new feature. The roll-out  of this new feature will be completed in early May.

You can find this in Microsoft 365 Message center, navigate to Microsoft 365 admin center->Health->Message center:

[image]

Roadmap: https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=34251

Comment: The message that you refer to does not seem to mention the quick links webpart. Only the various navigation types .

Answer (score 1):

Enabling audience targeting on the modern page web part is not available by default - there is a SharePoint user voice for this requirement, Microsoft has planned to release this in phases from one type of web part to another type.

The last update from Microsoft was:

"We’re working on this! The first web part we’re enabling it on is the **News web part**, followed by the **highlighted content** and **events web parts**. We’d love to hear about other audience targeting scenarios you’d like us to enable. Thanks!"

Here is the original thread about the above requirement:

[Enable Audience targeting on modern page web parts](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/20101822-enable-audience-targeting-on-modern-page-web-parts#%7Btoggle_previous_statuses%7D)

As an alternate, you can go with developing a custom web part using SPFx framework for the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is introducing an audience targeting feature for the **Quick links web part** in SharePoint Online, Check the [Roadmap](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=67115).

Currently it's status is "In development" and it will be available soon for all (January CY2021).

Check more information about this at: [Audience Targeting for Quick Links Web Part in SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/17/audience-targeting-for-quick-links-web-part-in-sharepoint-online/)